# Getting wired result from max function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python3.6.2, I was trying to find the longest word in a sentence.
The code I came up with is,

```
 >>> sen = "Argument goes here"

 >>> max(sen.split())

 'here'
```

I would like to why is the answer '**here'** instead of **'Argument'**, rather than the answer to the problem.

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: max is comparing your strings in lexical order not length of string

Comment: Would you please explain to me what is lexical order or give any links to know about it @SungJin Steve Yoo

Comment: See here. http://thepythonguru.com/python-strings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **SungJin Steve Yoo** pointed out, [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function by default compares `string` in `Lexological Order`, and here, the string length does not come into play.

So, when you do

```
max( ['Argument', 'goes', 'here'] )
```

Here, the starting letter `h` has higher order compared to both `A` and `g`.

In case you wanted to do it by `length` and `lexological order`, use the `key` function :

```
max(sen.split(), key= lambda x:(len(x), x) )
```

*Below are a few cases for you to get the hang of it :*

```
>>> sen = sen = 'hex men or -'

>>> max(sen.split())
=> 'or'
>>> max(sen.split(), key=len)
=> 'hex'
>>> max(sen.split(), key= lambda x: (len(x), x))
=> 'men'
```

Comment: Great. nice answer

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo : Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do not mention the `key` function of `max`, it will just take default ordering of the itearbles; in this case, the lexical order. You need to mention that you need to order by `len`. You need to do this:

```
>>> sen = "Argument goes here"
>>> max(sen.split(), key=len)
'Argument'
```